# Grass stops lawnmower pulls up grass

Tags: lawn-repair

When I cut my grass their are spots that stop the lawnmower and seem to pull up sections of the grass, it seem to be really thin at those points and those spots turn brown later.

Comment: What type of lawn mower? Reel, rotary, ride on, push, self propelled...

Comment: @randy Is it possible that your blade is upside down? Have you recently changed or sharpened the blade?